# How to Solve this Limit for x going to zero?

Tags: limits

I'm having big troubles trying to solve this limit:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \quad x(2-x)\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{4e^{-2x}}{(1-e^{-2*x})^{2}}} + x$$

The result is zero, but I can't figure out how to get there.

I was trying to make a "sandwich" by making an upper and lower approximation using the fact that $1/e < 1/(1+x)$ but this is getting me nowhere.
Rationalisation isn't helping either.

Thank you in advance for your inputs

Bests

Comment: can you follow the given answer? do not hesitate to ask for any doubt about it

Comment: Remember that you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given if it solved the OP, see here for details https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$x(2-x)\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{4e^{-2x}}{(1-e^{-2*x})^{2}}} + x=\frac{x(x-2)}{|x|}\sqrt{1-\frac{(2x)^2e^{-2x}}{(1-e^{-2x})^{2}}}+x=\frac x{|x|}(x-2)\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{2x}{1-e^{-2x}}\right)^2e^{-2x}}+x\to \pm1\cdot(-2)\cdot0+0=0$$

indeed $y=-2x\to 0$

$$\frac{2x}{1-e^{-2x}}=\frac{y}{e^{y}-1}\to 1$$

Comment: Some care when taking a variable out of a square root: $\;\sqrt\frac1{x^2}=\frac1{|x|}\;$ . Also, and this is more serious, the expression within the square root between parentheses is an indeterminate $\;\frac00\;$ ...This exercise seems to be way uglier that it looks...But your are pretty close, imo.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes of course for |x| I need to fix! Thanks. But I don't get the observation for the square root, we have a standard limit inside.

Comment: @gi Now you've showed, now you have it. Very nice. +1

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry at first I think it was clear, but then I've preferred to highlight it better. Thanks again for your very good pointing out on my fault about |x|.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you very much for your very good explanation!

Comment: @Sandra and me? :)

Comment: @gimusi of course also to you a big thank you ! :) without your observation I wouldn't have understand :)

Comment: @Sandra Well done! You are welcome. See you for other limits. Bye

Comment: @gimusi  Sorry it was my first question here, I got confused with your names. Anyway a very big thanks to both of you for your help, your time, your effort and your quick response! :)